# to check whether two elements in the list are same or not. if same print that particular element

Tags: python, list

I have a list of interger values. I want to find out whether two elements in the list are same or not . If same print that particular element.

the list is

```
lst = [344, 344, 590]
```

I used the code but it gives the boolean value whether two elements are same. I also want to print that particular element.Below code print the value `True` but I also want to print the element which is same for here `344`

```
def has1dup(lst):
    return len(lst)-1 == len(set(lst))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def has1dup(lst):
    setlst = list(set(lst)) # no duplicate elements
    for i in range(len(setlst)): # while the setlist's element count, 
        if lst.count(setlst[i]) > 1: # if the count of setlist[i] of lst is bigger than 1
            return setlst[i] # return it
lst = [344, 344, 590]
print(has1dup(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
def has1dup(lst):
    if len(lst) != len(set(lst)):
        return [True, [i for i in set(lst) if lst.count(i) > 1]]
    else:
        return False

lst = [344, 344, 590]
print(has1dup(lst))
```

Output:

```
[True, [344]]
```

This code checks whether there are duplicates in the list or not, if there are, it gives a `True` and I did a list comprehension that goes through the list, but I use `set` so it removes the duplicates first, then it checks if the element appears more than once in the list, it will return that value. If there are no duplicates it returns `False`.